# How to hide views for always

Tags: java, android, view

Can somebody tell me how to hide views for always?

I'm hiding a view with `view.setVisibility(view.GONE);` but when reopen the app I have to re-hide the view. I want a view hide for always when button is clicked until clearing app data or uninstalling. Thanks!

Comment: add your code so I can try to solve your problem.

Comment: Your current approach is probably what you will have to use to let a button toggle a view.  You could also set visibility from the layout XML which might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not option to permanent hide but you can achieve by this way

1.Remove the specific `view` by

```
parent.removeViewAt(index);

parent.removeView(view);
```

2. you have to save the state to `show/hide` the `view` on permanent storage like

   Share preference / databases

Shared Preference Example

1.store value in `sharedPrefernces`:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("SoldiPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("storevalue", false);
editor.commit();
```

2.get value from `sharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("SoldiPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.getBoolean("storevalue", false);

if(preferences.getBoolean("storevalue", false))
{
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: can you tell me please how to use 'SharedPreference' with '.setVisibility'

Comment: Can you give example of this with button  with button click to 'view.setVisibility(view.GONE);'

Comment: button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        
        imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("SoldiPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("storevalue", true);
editor.commit();
    }
});

Comment: and you also have to check in on create , for neXt time to be visible/gone.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save state by creating flag for hide and unhide view in `SharedPreference` and basis of that flag you need to GONE or VISIBLE View.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `SharedPreferences`, when you hide the `View` then store a value in `SharedPreferences`, and when you come back to the app get value from `SharedPreferences` and according to that value hide your `View` by the same method that you are using.

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor et = sp.edit();
et.putBoolean("isViewHide", true);
et.commit();
```

**Getting value from SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean cb1 = sp.getBoolean("isViewHide", false);
```

reference from [SharedPreferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39594870/6676466)

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is the programmatic one and is probably what you will have to use if you want a button to toggle the visibility of a view.  The only other option of which I am aware would be to disable visibility from the XML layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:visibility="gone"
    ... />
```