# How to set visibility GONE of views for always with shared preferences in Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have some views in fragment under TabLayout. I want these views to be hidden with 'view.setVisibility' for always (till clearing app data or uninstalling) after a clicking a button. Can somebody help me please. I don't think this question needs any  code to show you.

Comment: Something like `view.setVisibility(pref.toHide ? GONE : SHOW)` ? I don't get the problem, so you might need to add more information on what you can't do here.

Comment: this will surely help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962705/how-to-hide-views-for-always/44962743#44962743

Answer (score 2):

When the button is clicked set a boolean value as true in SharedPreference.

Then, in onCreate() function of the layout/fragment in which the views are inflated, check the value from SharedPreference and set the visibility accordingly.

Comment: @NiezwmxaBoro if you want a solution, first try to implement it yourself. If this doesn't work, edit the question with your latest try, this will be used to give a solution. We are not providing a free coding services. You have the solution, work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your UI with the `SharedPreference`. When your `onCreateView` of fragment is loaded you can check your `SharedPreferenceview` visible state and apply this flag to view visibility.

Comment: What are you adding to [codeWorm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44968993/4391450) answer ?

Comment: It will easy to manage in method onCreateView  in fragment. I would suggest you can get the flag in this method and show your UI.

Comment: But, again, that's already explain in [codeworm answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44968993/4391450). Yes, you use a different initialisation method to execute this, but this is just a comment on his answer.